# Write a character vector with some "\n" to a text file, replacing them with line breaks in R?

Tags: r, text, save

How to save a character vector containing some `\n` in a `.txt` file in R?

```r
char = "Name\nAddress\nAge"
```

Should I use `writeLines`?

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is. `writeLines` will happily write that to a file, and it will result in three lines of text. If you are trying to **encode** the newlines so that that is a single line of text, then: `gsub("\n", "\\\\n", char)` before writing. (This presumes that the consumer of that textfile will know what to do with it, since at that point it will be a "backslash-n" and not a "real" newline.)

Comment: I found out, `writeLines` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
writeLines(char, "filename.txt")
```